# Shell Sort and Confusion with gaps

Tags: algorithm, sorting, shellsort

I've recently seen and studied the shell-sort algorithm and the seen the example provided [here](http://cprogrammingcodes.blogspot.in/2012/02/shell-sorting.html). In the example they consider a 'inc' or 'gap'.

I made a c implementation of the algorithm, and taking the gap value as a parameter in the sort.

I am observing the fact that for 10 unsorted values which are :

> 5, 1, 3, 2, 4, 8, 6, 9, 7, 10

using any gap, I am getting the following output :

> 1       2       3       4       5       6       **8**       **7**      9   10

I've built a recursive version of the code, which is here :

```
void shellSort(int *arr, int size, int gap){
    int i, tmp;
    if (gap == 0) return;
    for (i = 0; i < size / gap; i+=gap){
        if (i < size - 1){//Valid Index
            if (arr[i] > arr[i + gap]){
                tmp = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[i + gap];
                arr[i + gap] = tmp;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("Interation : \n");
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        printf("%d\t", arr[i]);
    }
    printf("\n\n");
    shellSort(arr, size, gap - 1);
}
```

Example :

```
int main()
{
    int arr[] = { 5, 1, 3, 2, 4, 8, 6, 9, 7, 10 }, i;
    shellSort(&arr[0], 10, 3);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

After reading through the material in the internet, I am completely confused about selecting this gap value, in some places like wikipedia, they are using a gap sequence. Some assistance would be appreciated.

After Correction,

```
for (i = 0; i < size - gap; i++)
```

Output:

> 1       **3**       2       4       5       6       **8**       7    9   10

Answer (score 1):

1. This code is not shell sort, it is a kind of [comb sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comb_sort)
2. In this line
   `for (i = 0; i < size / gap; i+=gap)`
   index i doesn't walk through the whole array. Possible correction:
   `for (i = 0; i < size - gap; i++)`
3. For full sorting, you have to repeat sort with gap = 1 while swapping occurs. [Examples](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithms/Comb_sort)

Gaps are described in every manual about shellsort or combsort.
In short - two indexes, separated by gap, walk through array, so unordered elements are moving closer to their places in sorted array. After every run gap decreases (in shellsort denominator is 2-3, in combsort - 1.3). Decrementing gap by 1 (as your code shows) makes the code very slow.

Comment: Added result of the correction in the main thread. Doesn't solve and what is the significance of gap here

Answer (score 0):

In the Shell-Sort Algorithm, you need to understand the concept of gap-sorting an array (or h-sorting).

Assume that you have a gap 'h'. You will begin with the first element tab[0] and sort all the elements spaced by h in your array: tab[0], tab[h], tab[2h] ... then you will pick the secend element as a begining and try to sort the spaced elements. Each time the starting element is incremented. To sort the h-spaced elements, you use the insertion sort algorithm.

After that choose a sequence for your h-insertion sort code starting from the biggest gap.

This is my implementation in java:

```
// Using Pratt sequence 
public static void hSort(int tab[]) {
    int N = tab.length;    
    int k = 0;    
    int sequence = 1;

    // Getting the final term of the pratt sequence 
    while(((int)(Math.pow(3, k) - 1) / 2) < N/3) {
        sequence = (int)(Math.pow(3, k) - 1) / 2;
        k++;
    }     
    k--;

    while(sequence > 0) {
        hInsertionSort(tab, sequence);
        k--;
        sequence = (int)(Math.pow(3, k) - 1) / 2;
    }
}

public static void hInsertionSort(int[] tab, int h) {
    int N = tab.length;
    int k = 0;
    while (k < h) {
        for (int i = k; i < N; i+=h) {
            for (int j = i; j > k+h-1; j-=h) {
                if (less(tab[j], tab[j-h]) == -1) exch(tab, j, j-h);
                else break;
            }
        }
    k++;
    }

}

private static inttab[1] (it means sort tab[1], tab[h+1], ...). This is h-sorting your array. less(int value1, int value2) {
        if (value1 == value2) return 0;
        if (value1 < value2) return -1;
        else return 1;
}
tab[1] (it means sort tab[1], tab[h+1], ...). This is h-sorting your array.
private static void exch(int[] tab, int key1, int key2) {
        int inter;
        inter = tab[key1];
        tab[key1] = tab[key2];
        tab[key2] = inter;
}
```